# RSS Feed getting data from mysql database and outputting Â£ - How do I display £ instead of Â£ even though my feed is calling UTF8?

Tags: php, mysql, xml, rss

> This is the code it runs as I want it to but the output 'name' from the table in database always shows i.e. Â£101 instead of £101 what do I need to correct in the code shown?

```
<?php    
header('Content-type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8'); 

$host = "host"; 
$user = "testing"; 
$pass = "abcdefghikans"; 
$database = "test"; 

$linkID = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die("Could not connect to host."); 
mysql_select_db($database, $linkID) or die("Could not find database."); 

$rss = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'; 
$rss .= '<rss version="2.0">'; 
$rss .= '<channel>'; 
$rss .= '<title>Competition Feed</title>'; 

$numStart = gmmktime(0, 0, 0, date('m')-1, 1, date('Y'));
$numEnd = gmmktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), 1, date('Y'))-1; 
$sql = "SELECT name FROM table WHERE active = '0' AND closedate >= '$numStart' AND closedate <= '$numEnd' AND value >=100 ORDER BY value DESC"; 
$query = mysql_query($sql, $linkID) or die("Data not found."); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {  

$rss .= '<item>';
$rss .= '<description>'.$row['name'].'</description>';
$rss .= '</item>';

} 

$rss .= '</channel>'; 
$rss .= '</rss>'; 

echo $rss; 
?>
```

Comment: why don't you use http://php.net/XmlWriter instead?

Comment: It's fine I worked it out in the line where it shows $rss .= '<description>'.$row['name'].'</description>'; I altered it to show $rss .= '<description>'.utf8_decode($row['name']).'</description>';

Comment: Why don't you use XmlWriter instead?